# Quick way to determine the number of horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus, functions

I understand how to calculate horizontal and vertical asymptotes, both by using the trick of comparing the degrees of the numerator/denominator and by using calculus. What I would like to know is this: is there a quick way to determine whether or not a rational function (perhaps with just polynomials, perhaps with absolute values or nth roots) has just one horizontal asymptote or two? (And yes, I also know how to determine if a rational function has no asymptotes or one asymptote; I simply am curious whether or not there are certain kinds of functions that always have likely to have two horizontal asymptotes).
Thanks in advance for your help!